# Como fazer escape de todos os metacaracteres usando Pattern.compile(..)?

Tags: java, regex

Arquivo:

> ftp://paginaqualquer.html
>
> https://outrapagina.net/
>
> http://minhapagina.php?id=

Meu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     //Supondo que o readLine() esteja no loop != null
     String arquivoLinha = arquivo.readLine();
     Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile(arquivoLinha); //O problema está aqui
     Matcher texto = padrao.matcher("http://minhapagina.php?id=");
     while (texto.find()){
          System.out.println(texto.group());
     }
}
```

Quando a última linha chega na variável arquivoLinha(http://minhapagina.php?id), acontece o que eu não queria que acontecesse: O metacaractere "?" tem poder, sendo assim modificando minha pesquisa. Eu poderia até usar o escapador "\" pra ignorar o "?", mas como faço isso? Ou pelo menos ignorar qualquer metacaractere que esteja na variável arquivoLinha e considerar ele como literal.

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
Pattern.compile("["+"("+arquivoLinha+")"+"]");
```

Usando a linha dentro grupo, que dentro da lista pra ignorar os metacaracteres, só que não tá dando muito certo.

Comment: [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está precisando que o padrão compilado seja *literal*, ou seja, que meta caracteres ou caracteres de escape no padrão não tenham tratamento de expressão regular.

Para isto basta compilar o padrão informando um *flag* dizendo isto, que "escape" tais caracteres. Você encontra este *flag* no próprio `Pattern`, a [`LITERAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL).

Para compilar o padrão usando este *flag* basta fazer isto:

```
final Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("http://minhapagina.php?id=", Pattern.LITERAL);
final Matcher texto = padrao.matcher("http://minhapagina.php?id=");
while (texto.find()) {
    System.out.println(texto.group());
}
```

Isto fará com que seu padrão "case" como texto, então isto será impresso:

```
http://minhapagina.php?id=
```